# Rails When should I use strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am not sure if I understand the concept of strong parameters correctly. I should use strong parameters to params that I will use only to edit some data? Or I should use them for every params I want to get in controller? For example I want to get data between two dates, so I need date1 and date2 as params. Should I use here strong params or not?

Comment: Strong parameters are used for _mass assignment_ to explicitly allow (or deny) certain attributes from a larger data structure to be used. For single attributes, you can just use `params[:date1]`. (you are being explicit here)

Comment: Could you give some example to help me understand this?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to understand when you should use strong parameters is to understand what a mass assignment volunerability is. In Rails 3 you could do the following:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[3.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.boolean :admin
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 
end
```

Here we are just passing a "hash" (its actually an ActionController::Parameters instance) straight into the model. All a malicous user has to do here is request:

```
POST /users?users[admin]=1
```

And they have created an admin account. [In 2012 Egor Homakov famously exploited one such loophole in Github](https://gist.github.com/peternixey/1978249) to commit to the Rails repository.

Such an attack is trivial to perform with cURL or by using the web inspector to manipulate a form.

If we whitelist which attributes the user should be able to pass:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(
      params.require(:user)
            .permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    )
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 
end
```

Then this avoids the vulnerability - strong parameters is really just a simple  DSL for slicing and dicing nested hash like structures. What changed in Rail 4 is that when you pass a n instance of `ActionController::Parameters` to a model an exception is raised unless calling `#permitted?` on the parameters object returns true. This avoids a mass assignment vulnerability from occuring simply due to programmer laziness or ignorance.

It does not sanitize your inputs in any other way. Like for example it won't prevent SQL injection or remote code execution if you treat user input carelessly.

You don't need strong parameters  if you're passing parameters one by one like in this very contrived example:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new do |u|
      u.email = params[:user][:email]
      u.password = params[:user][:password]
      u.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
    end
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Worth noting that you shouldn't really implement your strong params in the way shown here. The code's correct, but it's better to have a private `[MODEL]_params`  method in your controller (e.g. `user_params`, `article_params`) that you can call from every method in that controller that needs access to the params. This makes it easier to get into the habit of using the strong params - there's rarely a reason NOT to use the strong params, and you'll know it when you hit it.

Comment: @JohnP the example is written for brevity. However extracting your strong parameters into a method doesn't actually have that much merit on its own except that it avoids duplication. There is no duplication in this example so thus no violation of DRY.

Comment: @JohnP as for the "it makes it easier to get into the habit" part - that's nonsensical as rails will raise an exception if you don't.

Comment: @max thanks man!

Comment: @max Rails won't raise an exception if you access `params` directly. Setting up the private `user_params` method or whatever by default and using that throughout is thus just sensible advice ISTM - you'll almost always be accessing parameters in your controller methods at some point! Of course, in a brief example, there's no duplication, but if we're trying to help people then suggesting best practices would seem sensible. (I intended no criticism of your answer - it's correct, as I said - just an improvement.)